# How to get full path of a windows service installation folder from c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-services

I developed a Winform in c#. I need to get a full path of my windows service that i installed before.

i can get some properties of the service with the following code:

```
            ServiceController ctl = new ServiceController("MyCustomService");
```

the service .exe resides here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Manufacturer\MyCustomService
```

but i need to get that path dinamically, from code... Is it possible?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Path of executing assembly `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` from the code of service.
If you want to get path from other application you can use `Registry.GetValue()` to get string value of `ImagePath` from key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\YourServiceName`, or make wrapper around  `sc qc YourServiceName`

Answer (score 0):

The Service Controller Class wont provide the full path of a windows service, You have to use either a WMI or registry

```
   WqlObjectQuery wqlObjectQuery = new WqlObjectQuery(string.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE Name = '{0}'", serviceName));
    ManagementObjectSearcher managementObjectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wqlObjectQuery);
    ManagementObjectCollection managementObjectCollection = managementObjectSearcher.Get();

    foreach (ManagementObject managementObject in managementObjectCollection)
    {
        return managementObject.GetPropertyValue("PathName").ToString();
    }
```

This [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26533/A-ServiceController-Class-that-Contains-the-Path-t) provide nice example of how to use registry to find the full path of service